USDZ File Oriented Wrong in Blender
I have imported the Biped Robot provided by Apple for rigging. When I import the USDZ file it looks like this:

I have used the FBX version of the file to rig my model. However, this one exports incorrectly. What is the best way to import/export these files in Blender so that I can use them in XCode?
I have tried exporting it as USDC and using Reality Compose and Converter to set the axis in a variety of orientations.
